# iPad app syncing with custom API over wired connection

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there any way to provide 2 way sync capabilities over a wired connection? The connection would be between an iPad app and a custom Web API. The app currently works over a wireless connection. However, one of our potential clients does not allow for wireless connections due to security restrictions.

Any help would be appreciated. Also, please let me know if more information needs to be provided.

Comment: Is the Web API running on the computer you will be wired to?

Comment: You might be able to do so if you enroll for the MFI program, but with you specification I don't think Apple will grant it. Apple has not api in the default SDK to do anything of the USB/Lighting/30-pins connector.

Comment: Web API will be running on a remote server. However, the computer that the iPad is wired to will have access to the Web API.